# I am converting my python script to a .exe but I get a Error that involves the Icon Bitmap

Tags: python, pyinstaller

This is the Error:
`File "XPperHR.py", line 121, in <module> File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 2136, in wm_iconbitmap _tkinter.TclError: bitmap "totem.ico" not defined`

Both the .ico and the .py are in the same directory("C:\Users\chaos\Downloads")

In the Python Script:`window.iconbitmap('totem.ico')`

I am using pyinstaller to convert it into a .EXE

`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --clean --icon='totem.ico' --add-data 'totem.ico;.' XPperHR.py`

I was looking trough other questions but couldnt really get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

Once a python script has been converted to a .exe with PyInstaller, you must change the path you reference your files with as they are bundled with the exe.

Add this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile) to your code, and import the os module:

```
import os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Use the function to change the path:

```
path = resource_path('totem.ico')
window.iconbitmap(path)
```